# 2009 iMac as 2nd Monitor – Can't adjust brightness

Tags: display, imac, thunderbolt, displayport, target-display

I am trying to use my 2009 iMac 27" as a second display for my 2013 MBPr 15" (both running El Capitan). I have connected the two with a thunderbolt cable and everything is working fine except one thing – once the iMac starts acting as a display for the MacBook, it switches to full brightness. When I open up display preferences, the brightness slider that is usually there is gone.

I have seen other people online who had this problem years ago, but was unable to find a solution. Is there any way to adjust the brightness on the iMac when using it as a second display?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly this problem still exists. My work around is as follows

```
1) Apple F2 to share displays. The screen is usually quite dark.
2) Apple F2 to switch back to iMAC display.
3) I can now adjust the brightness on the iMac, I set it to my desired level.
4) I Apple F2 back to the shared display I initially wanted.
```

It is indeed quite annoying and generally a bad experience.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the the thunderbolt port on MBP(2015) (same port on iMac(2014) and same cable) and it was solved.